# How 'for movie in someObjects as! [Movie]' should be read

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I am trying to learn the concept of keyword 'as!'. I saw the code below from 'The Swift Programming Language 2.1'.

My question is, how the code 'for movie in someObjects as! [Movie]' should be read. Is the 'movie in someObjects' evaluated first or is the 'someObjects as! [Movie]' part of the code evaluated first?

```
for movie in someObjects as! [Movie] {
    print("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below:

```
for movie in someObjects as! [Movie] {
    print("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

The `as` is executed first, so you get `someObjects as! [Movie]`. The "!" says you are guaranteeing that someObjects is an array of `Movie` and not something else and not nil.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now everything is clear to me!! Really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
for movie in someObjects as! [Movie] {
    print("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

This Evaluates as fallows:

`movie` 
is the object "Singular" in the list of 
`someObjects` "Plural" 
so the someObjects is [sequenceable] then the
`as! [Movie]` 
is just telling the compiler that it is of type
`[Movie]`
This is similar to Objective C
`isTypeOfClass`
 and makes it possible for the statements 
`movie.name` and 
`movie.director` to evaluate because we know it is of type
`[Movie]` and movies have a name property and director property.

I hope that helps let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Im confused there is no `is` keyword here.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was asking two question at the same time and got confused. Thank again for your help!! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I thought that might have happened because I saw your other question.

Comment: Haha I ask a lot of questions. Trying very hard learning swift.

Comment: No problem. Keep at it and Good Luck.

Comment: It would be a lot harder without people like you helping people like me out. Thanks again!